# How to categorize floating values in python using pandas library

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, categories, data-analysis

`    import pandas
    import numpy

```
#importing the dataset
data=pandas.read_csv('gapminder.csv',low_memory=False)

#setting variables to be worked with to numeric
data['urbanrate']=data['urbanrate'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
data['femaleemployrate']=data['femaleemployrate'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
data['lifeexpectancy']=data['lifeexpectancy'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

print("Count for urbanrate")
chk8=data['urbanrate'].value_counts(sort=False,dropna=False)
print(chk8)

sub1=data[['urbanrate','femaleemployrate','lifeexpectancy']]
print (sub1.head(25))

===========================================================================
def urban (row):
      if (row['urbanrate']<25.0):
          return 1
      if (data[['urbanrate']>=25.0 & data['urbanrate']<75.0]):
         return 2
      if (data['urbanrate']>75.0):
         return 3
sub1['urban']=sub1.apply(lambda row: urban (row),axis=1)
print (sub1.head(25))
============================================================================`
```

I want to categorize all the values of `urbanrate` (which are all floating point numbers like `24.56`,`88.98`,`77.65`) into 3 different categories (one is values for `<25`, another for `>=25 and <75` and last one for `>=75`) and store those values in a new variable (say urban). How can I do this? I have given my code. I executed it and its giving me error as:

> TypeError: ('cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]', 'occurred at index 1'))

Please help me

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'urbanrate':[10,20,25,30,40,75,80,100]})
print (df)
   urbanrate
0         10
1         20
2         25
3         30
4         40
5         75
6         80
7        100

bins = [0, 24.999, 74.999, 1000]
group_names = [1,2,3]
df['urban'] = pd.cut(df['urbanrate'], bins, labels=group_names)
print (df)
   urbanrate urban
0         10     1
1         20     1
2         25     2
3         30     2
4         40     2
5         75     3
6         80     3
7        100     3
```

Answer (score 1):

use 3 masks:

```
sub1.loc[sub1['urbanrate']<25.0,'urban'] = 1
sub1.loc[(sub1['urbanrate']>=25.0) & (sub1['urbanrate']<75.0),'urban'] = 2
sub1.loc[sub1['urbanrate']>75.0,'urban'] = 3
```

you can mask the rows that meet the boolean condition and set all of them in a vectorised manner, what you tried fails because:

```
if (data[['urbanrate']>=25.0 & data['urbanrate']<75.0]):
    return 2
```

here you trying to compare an array with a scalar value to produce a scalar boolean, this won't work, additionally although you used the correct operator you needed to enclose the conditions in parentheses `()`:

```
if (data[['urbanrate']>=25.0) & (data['urbanrate']<75.0]):
    return 2
```

Also your function is inconsistent, you called `apply` and passed `axis=1` this implies you're trying to operate on the row value and your first condition is fine:

```
if (row['urbanrate']<25.0):
          return 1
```

but in the subsequent conditions you're testing the entire `Series` which is entirely different

If you did the following it would have worked:

```
def urban (colData):
    if colData<25.0:
        return 1
    if (colData>=25.0) & (colData<75.0]):
       return 2
    if (colData>75.0):
       return 3
sub1['urban']=sub1['urbanrate'].apply(urban)
```

it wasn't necessary to operate row-wise here, you can pass the entire column/series as the arg to your function

Comment: `sub1['urban']=sub1['urban'].apply(urban)`  Now it showing error in this line as KeyError:urban.I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Hmm try `sub1['urban']=sub1['urbanrate'].apply(urban)`